# How can I check if a binary file is included in another one?

Tags: c

If I have 2 binary files one is 4460 characters and the second one is 42.

How can I check if the bigger file contains the smaller file in it consecutively?

```
int checkIfInfected(char* virusSignature, char* currentFileString, int len, int virusLen)
{
    int flag = FALSE;
    int counter = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len && !flag; i++)
    {
        if (currentFileString[i] == virusSignature[counter])
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter == virusLen)
            {
                flag = TRUE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

`currentFileString` is an array that contains the long file
`virusSignature` is an array that contains the short file...
it returns true even if it is not right...

Anyone has a fix?

Comment: Or take a look at the `memmem()` function. (which respects NULs in the data, but is a GNU extension)

Comment: but it is not a string it is a array of chars in binary

Comment: I would suggest the correct types. `char` -> `uint8_t` , `int` -> `size_t`

Comment: If you'd like to check if a 'file' contains one of multiple 'virus signatures', you could use one of the multiple string search algorithms such as [Aho–Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Algorithms_using_a_finite_set_of_patterns)

Comment: @joop you're right, I forgot it was for binaries while answering

Answer (score 1):

if you do not want to use `memmem`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

    const uint8_t *binSearch(const uint8_t *haystack, const uint8_t *needle, size_t haystackLength, size_t needleLength)
    {

        size_t nP = 0;

        while(haystackLength)
        {
            while(nP < needleLength)
            {
                if(*haystack == needle[nP])
                {
                    haystack++;
                    haystackLength--;
                    nP++;
                }
                else 
                {
                    nP = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(nP) return haystack - needleLength;
            haystack++;
            haystackLength--;
        }
        return NULL;
    }

int main(void) {
    uint8_t arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,56,123,87,98,104,3,1};
    uint8_t needle[] = {104,3,2};

    printf("%p\n", binSearch(arr, needle, sizeof(arr), sizeof(needle)));
    return 0;
}
```

or if your data does not have to be uint8_t

```
const void *binSearch(const void *hs, const void *ndl, size_t haystackLength, size_t needleLength)
{

    size_t nP = 0;
    const uint8_t *needle = ndl;
    const uint8_t *haystack = hs;
```